# Spacy text classification scores

Tags: nlp, spacy, text-classification

I'm quite new to NLP text classification and trying to apprehend the basics. It seems that Spacy is more suitable for my tasks and experience. I've read through all the docs and run the example code from https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-textcat with default plac parameters with my own output folder. Then, I wrote a testing file:

```
import spacy

output_dir="train_output_orig"

test_text = [
    "This movie sucked",
    "It's a great one",
    "I've watched a lot of films of this kind. A lot of them were more attractive for me",
    "This is a great movie",
    "This movie is terrible",
    "I love this movie",
    "This is a bad film",
    "So fucking dung!",
    "Very involving work with developed characters"
    ]
print("Loading from", output_dir)
nlp2 = spacy.load(output_dir)
for text in test_text:
    print(text, nlp2(text).cats)
```

and got results:

```
Loading from train_output_orig
This movie sucked {'POSITIVE': 0.6549780368804932}
It's a great one {'POSITIVE': 0.7863456606864929}
I've watched a lot of films of this kind. A lot of them were more attractive for me {'POSITIVE': 0.7664909958839417}
This is a great movie {'POSITIVE': 0.7897435426712036}
This movie is terrible {'POSITIVE': 0.4777064323425293}
I love this movie {'POSITIVE': 0.7530838847160339}
This is a bad film {'POSITIVE': 0.46895521879196167}
So fucking dung! {'POSITIVE': 0.6296740174293518}
Very involving work with developed characters {'POSITIVE': 0.8538092970848083}
```

Is it OK for Spacy model, or have I done something wrong? I mean there's quite narrow frontier between "positive" and "negative" labels. Even definitive "This is a bad film" earned 0.46 of "positive" rating. "I love this movie" got only 0.75 while "Very involving work with developed characters" got 0.83. At the same time, suggested in the original Spacy usage docs phrase "This movie sucked" got 0.65 "positive" score!

Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: Hi Sergey , the classfication model provides only positive score . You have to set the threshold(for the positive score) to create two labels(positive and negative).

Comment: Hi Gideon, thank you, I understand that. I mean these scores differ a little. I expected something like 0.1 and 0.9, not 0.65 and 0.75...

Answer (score 0):

The text classification will return a score for all labels in the model. The closer to 0, the more confident the model is that it ISN'T that. The closer to 1, the model is more confident that it is IT.

If there isn't much difference in your text when you have a negative sentiment, then I would say you need more training data.

Answer (score 0):

The reviews in the training data are typically much longer than your examples above. If you try some of the examples from `test` in the dataset, you'll see scores more like `{'POSITIVE': 0.9939502477645874, 'NEGATIVE': 0.006049795541912317}`.

Also, a model trained with that example script should have both `POSITIVE` and `NEGATIVE` labels in `cats`, so if you're only getting `POSITIVE`, something might have gone wrong? (The `cats` for those short examples basically look like I'd expect, though.)